# Pandas to_datetime error 'unconverted data remains'

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to convert date column in my Pandas DataFrame to datetime format. If I don't specify date format, it works fine, but then further along in the code I get issues because of different time formats.

The original dates looks like this `10/10/2019 6:00` in european date format.

I tried specifying format like so:

```
df['PeriodStartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PeriodStartDate'], 
          format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

which results in an error: `unconverted data remains 6:00`

I then tried to update format directive to `format="%d/%m/%Y %-I/%H"` which comes up with another error: `'-' is a bad directive in format '%d/%m/%Y %-I/%H'` even though I thought that `to_datetime` uses the same directives and `strftime` and in the latter `%-I` is allowed.

In frustration I then decided to chop off the end of the string since I don't really need hours and minutes:

```
    df['PeriodStartDate'] = df['PeriodStartDate'].str[:10]
    df['PeriodStartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['PeriodStartDate'], 
          format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

But this once again results in an error: `ValueError: unconverted data remains:` which of course comes from the fact that some dates have 9 digits like `3/10/2019 6:00`

Not quite sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

format `%H:%M` would work(*don't forget the `:` in between*)

```
pd.to_datetime('10/10/2019 6:00', format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

Out[1049]: Timestamp('2019-10-10 06:00:00')

pd.to_datetime('3/10/2019 18:00', format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

Out[1064]: Timestamp('2019-10-03 18:00:00')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried your solution, but this only comes with another error: ```time data '3/10/2019 18:00' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M' (match)```. Not really sure why.

Comment: @user2825403: it means your data is 24 hours format , you need `%H:%M`. The directive `%I` is for 12-hour format.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, I feel so dumb. I figured out what the issue was. For some reason I thought that hours were in a 12-hour format, but they were in fact in a 24-hour format, so changing directive to `"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"` solved it.